# Completely uninstall SQL. Have hidden instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have an instance titled 'SQLEXPRESS' remaining, when I try to install SQL 2014.

I have uninstalled every program with SQL in the name from Add/remove programs.

I cannot remove this, how can I perform a complete uninstall?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to restart your machine.

Also you can find help on the Microsoft [website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143412.aspx)